# How to save an array in the ViewState and be able to retrieve it AFTER the page has unloaded?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Take the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private List<Customer> CustomerList;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Quickly Illustrate  Creation of a List of that contains information;
            //CustomerList = (!this.IsPostBack) ? new List<Customer>() : new List<Customer>((Customer[])ViewState["Customers"]);
            if (IsPostBack)
                CustomerList = new List<Customer>((Customer[])ViewState["Customers"]);
            else
                CustomerList = new List<Customer>();
            // Convert the List to Array of Customers and Save To View State
            // Rather than Handling Serialization Manually
            //ViewState.Add("Customers", CustomerList.ToArray());

            // While Reading the View State Information - Of course
            // use correct checks to see the item is Not Null and All that... and then do:
            //Customer[] newArray = (Customer[])ViewState["Customers"];
            //List<Customer> newList = new List<Customer>(newArray);
            //for (int i = 0; i < CustomerList.Count; i++)
            //    Response.Write(CustomerList[i].CustomerName + "\r\n");

        }

       protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CustomerList.Count; i++)
                Response.Write(CustomerList[i].CustomerName + "\r\n");
            ViewState.Add("Customers", CustomerList.ToArray());
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer SingleCustomer = new Customer();
            SingleCustomer.CustomerName = TextBox1.Text;
            CustomerList.Add(SingleCustomer);
            ViewState.Add("Customers", CustomerList.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work.  Every time I click the Add button and the page reloads, I get a NullReferenceException for "`CustomerList = new List<Customer>((Customer[])ViewState["Customers"]);`" because it's not there in the ViewState.  Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page Unload is simply too late to set a ViewState variable

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx:

> The Unload event is raised after the
>   page has been fully rendered, sent to
>   the client, and is ready to be
>   discarded. At this point, page
>   properties such as Response and
>   Request are unloaded and cleanup is
>   performed.

ViewState itself is sent as hidden fields in the page - so if you've already sent the page to the client, then you can't later add to the ViewState.

Try the LoadComplete or PreRender event instead?